# Не работают якори на вкладках bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Друзья, при ссылке на якорь третьей вкладки (вкладка "Шкивы зубчатые", якорь возле текста "XL шкивы" http://test.servo.by/belts.html#xl_pulleys) открывается первая вкладка.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
        <div class="heading heading-border heading-middle-border heading-middle-border-center anchor">
            <h4 id="mxl_belt" style="font-weight: 200; padding-left: 25px"><strong>MXL</strong> зубчатые ремни</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Все нормально открывается, что я делаю не так?

Comment: В 2х браузерах проверял. Ссылка http://test.servo.by/belts.html#xl_pulleys все равно отправляет на первый таб, а не третий.

Comment: ааа. при прямой ссылке с якорем. не въехал сразу

Comment: так и не должно работать. скрипты с якорями на вкладках срабатывают на onClick. Вы же не кликаете по табам при открытии ссылки

Comment: есть решение данного вопроса?

Comment: 1. на фронтенде. при загрузке страницы разбирать урл. и в скрипте открывать нужную вкладку. 2. на бэкенде. разбирать урл и передавать html, где у вкладки установлен признак активности